# How do I change column type on SQLAlchemy declarative model dynamically?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am running mysql in production but would like to run a simple tests in a sqlite in memory db.

The legacy mysql db has tables with columns that are mysql specific types, Which are declared in declarative models (subclassing declarative_base). I would like to run some simple tests without going to mysql and so would need to swap out the columns of the model.

How do I do this? I've tried writing a patcher/unpatcher to swap out **table** in my model, but when I run some tests, I get

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) near ")": syntax error u'\nCREATE TABLE my_table (\n)\n\n' ()
```

Which makes my think that I am not patching the columns properly.

Does anyone know how I can do this? What am I doing wrong?

Currently, I create new columns and attach brand new Table object to `__table__` and save the old table.

The DB is created, create_all() is and convert_columns is run in setUp. drop_all() and revert_columns is run during tearDown in my tests

```
mysql_sqlite_mapping = {INTEGER: Integer,
                        MEDIUMINT: Integer,
                        TEXT: text}    

def convert_columns(self, my_class, mapping):
    for column in my_class.__table__.columns:
        if type(column.type) in mapping:
            replacement_col = Column(column.name,
                                     mapping[type(column.type)],
                                     primary_key=column.primary_key,
                                     nullable=column.nullable,
                                     key=column.key,
                                     unique=column.unique)

            converted_columns.append(replacement_col)

    self.registry[my_class] = my_class.__table__

    my_class.__table__.metadata.remove(my_class.__table__)
    my_class.__table__ = Table(my_class.__table__.name,
                               my_class.__table__.metadata)

    for column in converted_columns:
        my_class.__table__.append_column(column)

    return my_class

def revert_columns(self, my_class):
    saved_table = self.registry[my_class]

    metadata = my_class.__table__.metadata
    my_class.__table__.metadata.remove(my_class.__table__)

    model_class.__table__ = Table(saved_table.name,
                                  metadata)

    for column in saved_table.columns:
        column.table = None
        my_class.__table__.append_column(column)

    self.registry.pop(my_class)
```

Answer (score 10):

I hope the below might help you with a *better* way of dealing with these kind of modifications. But your error is weird as it has no columns in the `CREATE TABLE` clause, so I do not think this is a direct answer/solution to your question.

Anyways, instead of completely replacing the tables and columns, why don't you try to use the [Custom SQL Constructs and Compilation Extension / Dialect-specific compilation rules](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/compiler.html#dialect-specific-compilation-rules). See the sample code that should generate a proper SQL statement for sqlite without changing the table definitions:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import MEDIUMINT, INTEGER, TEXT

@compiles(MEDIUMINT, 'sqlite')
def compile_MEDIUMINT(element, compiler, **kw):
    """ Handles mysql MEDIUMINT datatype as Integer in sqlite.  """
    return compiler.visit_integer(element, **kw)

@compiles(INTEGER, 'sqlite')
def compile_INTEGER(element, compiler, **kw):
    """ Handles mysql INTEGER datatype as Integer in sqlite.  """
    return compiler.visit_integer(element, **kw)


@compiles(TEXT, 'sqlite')
def compile_TEXT(element, compiler, **kw):
    """ Handles mysql TEXT datatype as text in sqlite.  """
    return compiler.visit_text(element, **kw)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but how do I use this along with declarative? Rather, do I do @compiles on the fly? I would like to keep this out of my model, as it is for running tests only.

Comment: yes, this should be enough to generate the correct `DDL` statements.

Comment: N.B.: If you want to put these compiler extensions across multiple python files, it's a good idea to put them in their own Python module and then import that module in your `__init__.py`. Otherwise, simply putting these in the same module as the ORM classes is sufficient.